# Assignment to unallocated variable

Tags: fortran, gfortran, allocation

A line in my code assigns an array to an unallocated array. I thought it was a bug but to my surprise it works just fine.

```
program test
implicit none
    real, allocatable :: x(:,:)
    real :: y(2,2)

    y = 1.
    x = y

    print*, x
end program test
```

How does this work in terms of memory? The `=` operator here just allocates and assigns at the same time? Why is this possible and why is the compiler not complaining? I am using gfortran 5.4.0.

Comment: It might be a question on the same matter as the one linked as duplicate, but asked in a more clear way in my opinion (also easier to find). So I will leave it for the moment even though it has been marked as duplicate.

Comment: You certainly want to keep this question.  Being a duplicate is not inherently bad.  It is indeed clearer in one of the aspects covered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Fortran 2003, allocatable arrays will be automatically allocated (or re-allocated if the shape has changed) at run time. See for instance the Fortran 2003 features of the NAG compiler https://www.nag.com/nagware/np/r61_doc/nag_f2003.pdf or look for "realloc" in the documentation of gfortran https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Error-and-Warning-Options.html#Error-and-Warning-Options

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, according to Section 7.2.1.3, "Interpretation of intrinsic assignments" of [WD 1539-1](http://www.j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf), paragraph 3.